# Generate bundles when build or deploy package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

With web.optimization and by default, bundles and minification are generated in the first call. Is it possible to generate them when package is built or when package is deploying ?

Answer (score 0):

One strategy is to do a manual HTTP GET after deployment as part of your build script. My recommendation is to use something like `curl` to fire the request. This will force it to create your bundle. I can't think of a more elegant way, I'm afraid.

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html